# Operator Precedence in declaring more pointers in one instruction

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-precedence

I would like to understand why do i have to add an asterisk before each identifier when declaring more pointers with the same datatype on the same row.

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) is where i read from

---

*Another thing that may call your attention is the line:*

**int * p1, * p2;**

This declares the two pointers used in the previous example. But notice that there is an asterisk (*) for each pointer, in order for both to have type int* (pointer to int). ***This is required due to the precedence rules***. Note that if, instead, the code was:

**int * p1, p2;**

p1 would indeed be of type int*, but p2 would be of type int. Spaces do not matter at all for this purpose. But anyway, simply remembering to put one asterisk per pointer is enough for most pointer users interested in declaring multiple pointers per statement. Or even better: use a different statement for each variable.

---

The [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

**The question**: What rule is used here, what precedence is this? It is about comma or asterisk? I can't figure it out.

Comment: FWIW the rules about this are [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.decl) . It's about how the grammar of the language works, not operator precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any precedence rule. The gramma of a simple declaration looks like

```
decl-speciﬁer-seq init-declarator-listopt ;
```

The sign * belongs to declarators not to decl-specidier-seq as for example type specifier `int`.

So you may for example rewrite the declaration

```
int * p1, * p2;
```

like

```
int ( * p1 ), ( * p2 );
```

where `( *p1 )` and ( *p2 ) are decalartors (thouhg in this case the parentheses are redundant)

You may not write for example

```
( int * ) p1, p2;
```

The compiler will issue an error.

Parentheses are required when a more complicated type is declared. For example let's declare a pointer to an array

```
int ( *p )[N];
```

where N is some constant.

So you may enclose declarators in parentheses.

Let's consider a more complicated declaration: of a function that returns a pointer to function and has as a parameter another function

```
void ( *f( int cmp( const void *, const void * ) )( int *a );
```

As for the precedence then rules of building declarators describe them in the gramma

For example

if you will write

```
int * a[10];
```

then it is an array of 10 elements of the type `int *`.

However if you will write

```
int ( *a[10] );
```

then its an array of 10 pointers to objects of the type `int`.

If you will write

```
int ( *a )[10];
```

then it is a pointer to an array of 10 integers.

Take into account that typedef is also a decl-specifier.

So for example this typedef

```
typedef int *intPtr;
```

you may rewrite like

```
int typedef *intPtr;
```

or even like

```
int typedef ( *intPtr );
```

One more example of declaration. Let's consider a multidimensional array. In can be declared like

```
int ( ( ( a )[N1] )[N2] );
```

though again the parentheses are redundant. However they can help to understand how arrays are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements in expressions.

For example if you have an array

```
int a[N1][N2];
```

then to get a pointer declaration to its first element you can rewrite the declaration ,like

```
int ( a[N1] )[N2];
```

and now substitute `a[N1]` for `*a` (or for example *p).

```
int ( *p )[N2] = a;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not a precedence rule *per se*; rather, it is a rule that says that the `int` part applies to all the variables whereas the `*` only applies to the one right after it.

The general version of the rule is that all the *specifiers* in the declaration apply to every entity being declared. Specifiers include keywords like `constexpr` and `static`, as well as keywords that denote types like `int` and user-defined type names. The operators like `*` and `&` that modify the type specifiers to create more complex types, however, only apply to one entity at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There's no operator precedence involved here. In fact there are no operators either. Operators operate on expressions, but this is a declaration.

The syntax for declarations is that:

```
T D1, D2, D3, D4;
```

means the same as:

```
T D1; T D2; T D3; T D4;
```

where:

- `T` is *declaration-specifier*: no symbols, only keywords (e.g. `int`, `const`, `static`) and/or typedef-names.
- `Dn` is a *declarator*,  that is, an identifier (the name of the variable) perhaps with `*`, `[]` or `(parameter-list)` or grouping parentheses attached in various ways.

In your first example `T` is `int`,  and the declarators are `*p1` and `*p2` .

Comment: shouldn't be the declaration-specifier `int*` ? Isn't that the datatype?

Comment: OK i've read underneath that the sigm * belongs to declarators not to declaration-specifiers!